# Multiple instances of resize function jQuery/jS

Tags: jquery

Hello I found a good resize timeout function that fires a function(s) of your choice on window resize after a short timeout.

Here it is:

```
var animationsResize;
var anotherVariable;
window.onresize = function(){
    clearTimeout(animationsResize);
    animationsResize = setTimeout(checkWidthAnimations, 500);

    clearTimeout(anotherVariable);
    anotherVariable = setTimeout(anotherFunction, 500);
};
```

This runs my custom functions `checkWidthAnimations` and `anotherFunction` when a user stops resizing the window after 500 milliseconds.

What I did above works for my but here is where I encounter my problem. When I wrap another function inside of a window load function and then create an instance of this, it does not work. Here is my code that I need to fix.

```
var animationsResize;
var anotherVariable;
var windowLoadVariable;
window.onresize = function(){
    clearTimeout(animationsResize);
    animationsResize = setTimeout(checkWidthAnimations, 500);

    clearTimeout(anotherVariable);
    anotherVariable = setTimeout(anotherFunction, 500);

    clearTimeout(windowLoadVariable);
    windowLoadVariable = setTimeout(windowLoadFunction, 500);
};

jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
    function windowLoadFunction() {
        //my function
    }
});
```

Seems like the window.onresize function cannot read my `windowLoadFunction`

Does anyone have a solution to make it so I can add my `windowLoadFunction` to the resize function?

I tried adding another instance of the resize function into the window load function like this:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
    function windowLoadFunction() {
        //my function
    }

   var windowLoadVariable;
   window.onresize = function(){
       clearTimeout(animationsResize);
       windowLoadVariable = setTimeout(checkWidthAnimations, 500);
   });
});
```

This made the `checkWidthAnimations` work, but then broke the other two functions `checkWidthAnimations` and `anotherFunction`.

Anyone have an idea how to get all of them working together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends why you are defining your `windowLoadFunction` in the callback of the window load event... inside that scope, indeed, it can't be reached from the code outside. Would it be possible for you to define the function outside of the window load callback, and then just invoke it after the window loads?

```
var animationsResize;
var anotherVariable;
var windowLoadVariable;
window.onresize = function(){
    clearTimeout(animationsResize);
    animationsResize = setTimeout(checkWidthAnimations, 500);

    clearTimeout(anotherVariable);
    anotherVariable = setTimeout(anotherFunction, 500);

    clearTimeout(windowLoadVariable);
    windowLoadVariable = setTimeout(windowLoadFunction, 500);
};

function windowLoadFunction() {
    // your function
}

jQuery(window).on('load', windowLoadFunction);
```